# how to reseed in pymssql

Tags: python-2.7, pymssql, dbcc

I wish to reseed the userprofile table from python code. I have done as below

```
stmt =  "DBCC CHECKIDENT ('UserProfile', RESEED,52)"
cursr.execute(stmt)
```

But it is not getting set. I checked with

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('UserProfile',NORESEED) in sql server
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you use NORESEED when you want to reseed?

Comment: @danielkullmann question modified. thax for pointing it out

Comment: Do you need to do a commit() on the connection? If you haven't connect with the autocommit option, you probably just need to commit.